# In trying to rename columns on a csv file, the data is wiped out of the second and third columns

Tags: powershell, export-csv

## process that fails to get the desired result:

```
Import-Csv -Path C:\Data\Out2.csv | select A, G, H |Export-Csv C:\Data\Out3.csv -NoTypeInformation
Import-Csv C:\Data\Out3.csv |
 Select-Object @{n='Server Name';e={$_.A}} , @{n='Command';e={$_.B}}, @{n='Path';e={$_.C}} |
     Export-Csv C:\Data\Out4.csv -NoTypeinformation
```

Comment: From your Select only columns A,G,H remain in out3.csv so how do you expect to name the 2nd B and the 3rd C?

Comment: Thank you. This did work for me. Hard to see the difference other than you placed on 3 separate lines. Well, I am new to this. You saved me again, sir. Richtig vielen Dank!

Comment: That was just to enhance readabilty. But I chose the correct column names `$_.G` and `$_.H`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your Select only columns A,G,H remain in out3.csv so how do you expect to name the 2nd B and the 3rd C?

This could work:

```
Import-Csv -Path C:\Data\Out2.csv | select A, G, H |Export-Csv C:\Data\Out3.csv -NoTypeInformation
Import-Csv C:\Data\Out3.csv |
 Select-Object @{n='Server Name';e={$_.A}} , 
               @{n='Command';e={$_.G}}, 
               @{n='Path';e={$_.H}} |
     Export-Csv C:\Data\Out4.csv -NoTypeinformation
```

Was focused to much on the obvious error, the first select,export and re-import and so the intermediary file out3.csv aren't neccessary:

```
Import-Csv -Path C:\Data\Out2.csv | 
 Select-Object @{n='Server Name';e={$_.A}} , 
               @{n='Command';e={$_.G}}, 
               @{n='Path';e={$_.H}} |
     Export-Csv C:\Data\Out4.csv -NoTypeinformation
```